# Problem centering subfloat

Tags: pgfplots, subfloats, pgfplotstable

Try running this code removing one by one each `\pgfplotstablegetelem`. You will see that the 2 subfloats will move step by step to the center. Why? Keeping all of them the result is the following. I need to keep the `\newcommand` in this way, but at the same time the figure centered, how can I do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, filecontents}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}


\newcommand{\iso}[1]{
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{T}\of{coefficienti.dat}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\T}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{K}\of{coefficienti.dat}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\K}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Q}\of{coefficienti.dat}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Q}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Kf}\of{coefficienti.dat}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Kf}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{n}\of{coefficienti.dat}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Klf}\of{coefficienti.dat}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Klf}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Qlf}\of{coefficienti.dat}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Qlf}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{m}\of{coefficienti.dat}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{\pgfplotsretval}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=7cm,
            domain=0:1,
            xlabel=$Equilibrium$,
            ylabel=$Sorbed$,
            legend style={draw=none, at={(.9,.3)}}]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

}


\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{coefficienti.dat}
T       K       Q       Kf      n       Klf     Qlf     m
400     0.0463  32.9        5.78        0.321   .0840   40.7        .675
500     0.154   23.8        6.33        0.281   .0722   86.8        .354
600     0.115   24.6        6.30        0.261   .0257   247     .280
700     1.68        24.2        12.1        0.153   .9760   32.0        .376
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\iso{0}}
    \subfloat[]{\iso{0}}
    \caption{This caption is centered, but not the 2 subfloats}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good supply of end of line spaces. Put `%` at the end of lines, at will.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, filecontents}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}


\newcommand{\iso}[1]{%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{T}\of{coefficienti.dat}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\T}{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{K}\of{coefficienti.dat}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\K}{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Q}\of{coefficienti.dat}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Q}{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Kf}\of{coefficienti.dat}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Kf}{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{n}\of{coefficienti.dat}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Klf}\of{coefficienti.dat}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Klf}{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Qlf}\of{coefficienti.dat}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Qlf}{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{m}\of{coefficienti.dat}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{\pgfplotsretval}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \begin{axis}[
            width=7cm,
            domain=0:1,
            xlabel=$Equilibrium$,
            ylabel=$Sorbed$,
            legend style={draw=none, at={(.9,.3)}}]
        \end{axis}%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{coefficienti.dat}
T       K       Q       Kf      n       Klf     Qlf     m
400     0.0463  32.9        5.78        0.321   .0840   40.7        .675
500     0.154   23.8        6.33        0.281   .0722   86.8        .354
600     0.115   24.6        6.30        0.261   .0257   247     .280
700     1.68        24.2        12.1        0.153   .9760   32.0        .376
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\iso{0}}
    \subfloat[]{\iso{0}}
    \caption{This caption is centered, but not the 2 subfloats}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `width=7cm` is too much to fit in. Use `width=0.5\linewidth` instead.

[image]

Comment: thanks man!! why % is so important? I see that some people put it at the end of each line

Comment: @Stefano You will find the answer here: [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453)